# Read Excel in Python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have an .xlsx file with cells having background color, but when i am reading that file into pandas with read_excel. Is there any way to get the excel as it is(with background color).

i am using below code.

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_excel("My_Excel.xlsx")
df
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas library is for analyzing and working on data so you can't import style using it.

If you want to mark specific records you can use condition on them, or if you are categorizing a column for ex with 2 colors you can create a new column that indicates the value you're trying to map.